# Black screen after booting.

Tags: release-loki, boot, display

Help me please, my computer cannot access desktop and stuck after booting, just black screen.

Comment: Could you please give us more details? Like does it reach the elementary logo or the login prompt? Or can you remember if you updated the system before the said boot-up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After my install i believe i had the same problem.  When i installed my drivers a message popped up saying i needed to disable secure boot, i clicked the check mark and restarted and had a black screen with a flashing dash in the upper right corner.  What i had to do was reboot into BIOS, find the "Secure Boot" section and manually disable it, after that no more black screen for me, goodluck!